# Redirect site to 410 except one URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have site build in PHP codeigniter which has various URLs as follows:

```
    www.mysiteexample.com
    www.mysiteexample.com/mobile
    www.mysiteexample.com/storage
    www.mysiteexample.com/stack
    www.mysiteexample.com/apple and so on..
```

Now I want to redirect all the URLs to 410 gone including homepage but except `www.mysiteexample.com/stack` I am able to do this by adding separate rules for each URL as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/?mobile- [L,R=410]
RewriteRule ^/?storage- [L,R=410]
RewriteRule ^/?apple - [L,R=410]
```

But I want optimized solution for because I have more than 50 URLs which I want to redirect to 410 and using above solution it increases file size and LOC of .htaccess

**Edit:** 
I have following code in routes.php

```
$route['stack(.*)'] = 'stack_center/index';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below rule too, for now I didn't tried it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !stack
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=410]
```

Comment: Using this it is showing 410 for all site but for stack it is showing 404 error.

Comment: stack is file/directory or it is a value passing to index.php

Comment: stack is not file/directory or it is not any value. It is a URL structure or door page.Please see my edits

Comment: You have to write a code inside your route file for this because in real every request is transferred to index.php, apache can't do anything about your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Redirect

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^/((?!stack).*)$
```

Comment: Using this it is showing 410 for all site but for stack it is showing 404 error.

Comment: Does /stack exist in your filesystem?

Comment: No it dose not exists in filesystem. It is a URL structure or door page.Please see my edits